# Changing Initial View Controller Shown in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I just started programming with swift a few months ago and I am currently working on a few random projects to help me learn the language better. Currently, I am trying to create a UI similar to Snapchat's by using a UIPageViewController. The horizontal scroll is working and I can navigate through the pages correctly but I want to change the initial view controller that is presented. In my code below, I have three ViewControllers (vc1, vc2, vc3). I want to keep them in that same order but display vc2 first, so basically have it in the middle of the other two. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    let Cards = CardsVC()

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesVC")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardsVC")
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")

        return[vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{
            //logout()
        //}else{
        self.dataSource = self

        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first{
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    //}
    }

    func logout(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let verifyPhoneVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "enterPhoneNumber")
        present(verifyPhoneVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1
        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else {return nil}

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the entire code ready, all that you need to do is pass the secondViewController from the viewControllerList in viewDidLoad thats all

So replace

```
if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first{
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

with

```
let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1]
    self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @a-albert: you are always welcome buddy :) am glad I could help :) happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Here I have written an extension in swift 3 for navigating next and previous page in UIPageViewController. You can modify as your requirement.

extension UIPageViewController {

```
func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true) {
    guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
    guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }
    setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: nil)
}

func goToPreviousPage(animated: Bool = true) {
    guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
    guard let previousViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController) else { return }
    setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: animated, completion: nil)
}
```

}

I hope you find it useful. 
Open to suggestions.